# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Form Submit' is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

While click on a save button in my MVC 4 Application i am facing the issue "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Form Submit' is undefined". Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

DKT

Comment: Without any code, it's hard to help ...

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys this issue i as facing because i have not added that method in my page.
it was a very silly mistake